# How to increase performance for forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class AdmItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    mainimage = forms.ImageField(widget=AdmImageWidget(), required=False)
    tags = TagField(required=False)
    .....

class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ('id', 'category', 'date', ....)
```

but... In the articles table is 10 000 records... Form isn't opened, browser loads data forever.

What happens? Is the ModelChoiceField retrieves all data from a table?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got 10,000 records belonging to your `Article` model, then the queryset you're passing to `ModelChoiceField` will mean that it contains 10,000 items.

The simple solution is to restrict that queryset to contain only what you actually need: does the form need to contain every single article?

Long story short, see if you can restrict the query in any way, i.e.:

```
id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Article.objects.\
    filter(published=True))
```